# How to simply switch FTP connections for a project in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: configuration, aptana3

I have established several connections in Aptana Studio as FTP links, I have two connections usually for each site/project, one points to the Live source location and another to a test source location.

When working on a project I initially want to upload changes I make to the test environment, when I am happy I then want to upload the changed files to the live environment.

However I can't seem to switch connections easily in the project, the only way so far I have managed is to delete the connection and reconnect (to the environment I now want to FTP to). This requires re-entering the FTP configuration details, it's not a big job but I'd rather just be able to point the project at different connections when I want to use them, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window > Show View > Project Explorer`

`Right click on your project > Publish > Connections > Connection Manager`

Create whatever connections you need.

Now when you go to upload or sync, you will be offered a choice for which connection you want to use. You can also choose to make one of the connections the default so that you won't be prompted while you are working on your staging server for a long time, for instance. Then when you are ready to move to the live server, you can go into `Project > Properties > File Transfer` and clear the box `Use the connection as default` or just choose the one you want from the drop down.

Comment: Thank you, also it helped me to look at these as two different things - a Project connection (shown in Project Explorer) and an FTP connection (shown in Remote window), because I had named them the same (and the Icon used by Aptana is the same) I was getting confused by thinking they were the same thing, but it helps to understand how Aptana works to treat them as two different things. (also if you delete a project connection and it is the last one using the FTP connection it appears to delete the FTP connection also).